# how to remove the content of grid cell in swt?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, jface

In my wizard page I am using gridlayout with 3 colums. The 3 column will have remove button. I am using add button for the composite. when i push add button it will add new row to the grid layout. 
Now I am trying to add listener to remove button. When I push the remove button it should remove the row in which the remove button is pushed from the gridlayout and should resize the composite.
How to achieve this. And how to get the row index of the gridlayout?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the controls completely you need to call `dispose()` on each control and then call `layout()` on the parent composite.

`GridLayout` does not make any information about the positions of the controls available so you can't really get a row index. It does sound like you might be better using a `TableViewer` to show a proper table.

Comment: Thank you very much, I had a similar problem as the original poster and was able to solve it thanks to your post!!!